# How long do Azure Service Bus messages live once delivered?

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm being asked by the powers that be to not '`CompleteAsync`' the message I receive from Azure Service Bus until AFTER the job (initiated by the Service bus message) is completed, which could be up to seven hours after i receive the initial message.

In Azure portal Service bus setting, I have the following setting:

- Message time to live (days)
- Lock Duraction (Seconds)
- Duplicate detection history (minutes)
- Maximum delivery count

It appears once I initially receive the message (but do not respond), that the message keeps getting resent. Does "Message time to live" dictate how long it will keep retrying for?

Will the scenario of 'receive but close many hours later' work with how Service Bus functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read description about these settings here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription?view=azure-dotnet.

From this link:

- **Message time to live (days)**: Gets or sets the default message time to live value. This is the duration after which the message expires, starting from when the message is sent to Service Bus. This is the default value used when TimeToLive is not set on a message itself.Messages older than their TimeToLive value will expire and no longer be retained in the message store. Subscribers will be unable to receive expired messages.A message can have a lower TimeToLive value than that specified here, but by default TimeToLive is set to MaxValue. Therefore, this property becomes the default time to live value applied to messages.
- **Lock Duraction (Seconds)**: Gets or sets the duration of a peek lock; that is, the amount of time that the message is locked for other receivers. The maximum value for LockDuration is 5 minutes; the default value is 1 minute.
- **Duplicate detection history (minutes)**: Gets or sets the TimeSpan structure that defines the duration of the duplicate detection history. The default value is 10 minutes.
- **Maximum delivery count**: Gets or sets the maximum delivery count. A message is automatically deadlettered after this number of deliveries.

> It appears once I initially receive the message (but do not respond),
>   that the message keeps getting resent. Does "Message time to live"
>   dictate how long it will keep retrying for?

Not really. The number of times a message will be retried will depend on `Max Delivery Count`. Once a message has been delivered that many times, it will be sent to dead-letter subqueue.

Message `Time-to-Live` defines the time period after which a message will be removed from the queue. It could either be permanently deleted or sent to dead-letter subqueue if the [`EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.enabledeadletteringonmessageexpiration?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueDescription_EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration) property is set to true.

Comment: it appears if I 'defer' the message then it would allow me to respond at a much later time and it wont keep sending the message, [BokeredMessage.Defer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.defer). but my 'queueClient' doesn't have that method :-S

Comment: That's correct. The message will be kept somewhere safe and will be delivered at a later time and not immediately.

Comment: Thats kinda exactly what i want, but then it looks like i have to use a whole different set of libraries to do it? I'm using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.IQueueClient.RegisterMessageHandler, so i'm a bit lost. Bit late in the project to rewrite all the service bus code

Comment: I believe the link I shared is for the older library (just to give you an explanation about these various properties) and you're using the newer version which is the right way to go. My recommendation would be to ask a new question with the problems you're facing.

Comment: As soon as you posted the question, I found an answer for you :).

Answer (score 0):

Azure service bus uses a Lock mechanism the prevent multiple consumers from handling the same message. However, in order to prevent messages to be locked forever (e.g. get lock then process crash), Azure Service Bus has a failsafe that will automatically release the lock after a period of time (Lock Duration).

`Message time to live` is used to specify how long can a message stay in the queue without being picked up. After that delay, it will be automatically removed from the queue.

Comment: when Azure Service bus calls my "RegisterMessageHandler" method, does that count as it being 'picked up', or is 'picking up' a message when I tell service bus to 'close' the message? Looks like i need to rewrite anyhow as the azure library i'm using wont let me 'defer' as another answer suggests is possible